# Proof that $\phi:C[0;1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have problem with proof that $\phi:C[0;1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphism.

$ C[0;1], \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ - vector spaces.

Definition of $ \phi $: $ \phi(\varphi) = (\varphi(r_1),...,\varphi(r_n),...)$ where {$ r_i\in [0;1] $ $ i\in \mathbb{N}$ } some fixed set.

I don't know how to explain that $\phi$ is bijection, at least using only definition of bijection.

And I don't what property of continuous function I need to use for proof there equals:

$\phi(\varphi_1+\varphi_1) = \phi(\varphi_1)+ \phi(\varphi_2)$ $ \varphi_1,\varphi_2 \in C[0;1]$

$\phi(\alpha\varphi_1) = \alpha\phi(\varphi_1)$ $ \alpha\in\mathbb{R}, \varphi_1\in C[0;1]$

Could you please give any ideas how to prove that $\phi$ is isomorphism ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141213/discussion-on-question-by-freed-proof-that-phic01-rightarrow-mathbbr).

Comment: These two spaces are isomorphic as vector spaces.  But any isomorphism would be far less constructive than the one you propose.  In fact, it is likely not possible to "write down" an isomorphism.  An isomorphism is along the lines: choose Hamel bases for the two spaces, argue that the two bases have the same cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$, then define your isomorphism in terms of those bases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\phi$ is never a bijection.

Let $R = \{r_i\}$ which is an **infinite set**. More precisely we have a *bijection* $r : \mathbb N \to R, r(i) = r_i$.

Note that $\phi(f) = \phi(g)$ means that $f \mid_R = g \mid_R$.

- $\phi$ is injective if and only if $R$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

1. Let $R$ be dense. Let $\phi(f) = \phi(g)$. Then $f$ and $g$ agree on the dense subset $R \subset [0,1]$. For each $x \in [0,1]$ there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $R$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$. By continuity of $f,g$ we get $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n) = g(x)$. Thus $f = g$.
2. Let $R$ not be dense. Then there exists $\xi \in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon) \cap R = \emptyset$. Note that $(\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon)$ is not necessarily a subset of $[0,1]$, but this is irrelavnt here. The above condition means that each point of $R$ has  distance $\ge \epsilon$ from $\xi$. Define $G :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, G(x) = 0$ for $x \notin  (\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon)$, $G(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}(x - \xi)^2$ for $x \in  [\xi-\epsilon,\xi+\epsilon]$. Now consider $f(x) = 0$ and $g = G \mid_{[0,1]}$. Then $f \ne g$, but $\phi(f) = \phi(g)$.

- $\phi$ is not surjective.

Since $R$ is infinite, it has an accumulation point $\xi \in [0,1]$. Let $(r_{i_k})_{k \in \mathbb N}$ be a subsequence of $(r_i)$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} r_{i_k} = \xi$. Define a sequence $(s_i) \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ by $s_i = 0$ for $i \in \{i_1,i_3,i_5,i_7,\ldots \}$ and $s_i = 1$ for  $i \notin \{i_1,i_3,i_5,i_7,\ldots \}$. Assume that $(s_i) = \phi(f)$ for a continuous $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$. This means $f(r_i)  = s_i$ for all $i$. But we have $f(\xi) = f(\lim_{l \to \infty} r_{i_{2l+1}}) = \lim_{l \to \infty}f(r_{i_{2l+1}}) =  \lim_{l \to \infty}s_{i_{2l+1}} = 0$ and $f(\xi) = f(\lim_{l \to \infty} r_{i_{2l}}) = ) = \lim_{l \to \infty}f(r_{i_{2l}}) =  \lim_{l \to \infty}s_{i_{2l}} = 1$, a contradicton.